# Como mostrar datos de un 1 criterio en un listview

Tags: android, sql-server, android-listview

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación para hacer consultas de una base de datos en SQLserver,ya cree la lista y la conexión a la base de datos todo funciona bien, Mi problema es que cuando ingreso el nombre de un articulo o el Id en el EditText, la aplicación se detiene y deja de funcionar.

El error esta cuando creeo la instrucción en el query ya al final en el Where y se supone que todo esta bien escrito entonces no me explico porque no funciona cuando escribo el nombre del articulo o los articulos que tienen el mismo nombre en el EditText.

Les dejo el codigo que tengo:

```
 public class Consultar_Articulo extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText clave;
ListView list;
Button mostrar;
Connection connect;
String ConnectResult = "";
Boolean isSuucess=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capturar__articulo);

    clave = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clave_art);
    mostrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mostrar);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

}

SimpleAdapter adapter;
public void sqlButton(View view) {

    List<Map<String,String>> MyDatalist = null;
    Consultar_Articulo listaa = new Consultar_Articulo();
    MyDatalist  = listaa.getlist();

    String Fromw[] = {"ProductoID", "IName", "Des", "Precio", "Existencia", "Col"};
    int Tow[] = {R.id.ProductID, R.id.IName, R.id.Des, R.id.Precio, R.id.Existencia, R.id.Col};

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Consultar_Articulo.this, MyDatalist, R.layout.listlayouttemplate, Fromw, Tow);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public List<Map<String,String>>getlist(){

    List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
    data = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    try{
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        connect = conexionSQL.conclass();
        if(connect != null){

            String query = "select t1.articulo, t1.numero_de_parte, t1.nombre_detallado, t2.precio_1, t3.existencia_actual From Articulos As t1 " +
                    " Left Join precios_de_venta As t2 On t1.articulo = t2.articulo and t1.empresa = t2.empresa and t2.sucursal = 1 " +
                    " Left Join articulos_existencias As t3 On t1.articulo = t3.articulo and t1.empresa = t3.empresa and t3.sucursal = 1 " ;
                   // " Where numero_de_parte like '%" + clave.getText().toString() + "%' " + " Or nombre_detallado like '%" +  clave.getText().toString() + "%'";

            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);


            while (rs.next()){
                Map<String,String> dtname = new HashMap<String, String>();

                dtname.put("ProductID",rs.getString("articulo"));
                dtname.put("IName",rs.getString("nombre_detallado"));
                dtname.put("Des",rs.getString("numero_de_parte"));
                dtname.put("Precio",rs.getString("precio_1"));
                dtname.put("Existencia",rs.getString("existencia_actual"));
                data.add(dtname);

            }

            ConnectResult = "Success";
            isSuucess = true;
            connect.close();
        }else{

            ConnectResult = "Failed";
        }

    }catch (SQLException throwables){
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, recuerda que es super importante revisar el LogCat y copiar el mensaje de error que se genera cuando se cierra la aplicación, de otra forma las causas de cierre de la app pueden ser diversas, saludos

Comment: muchas gracias ya pude solucionar los errores que tenia